# Как найти максимальные числа (не одно а несколько)?

Tags: python

Дана строка, содержащая последовательность латинских слов, разделенных пробелами. Определить букву, встречающуюся в словах чаще всех остальных. Если такая буква не одна, то вывести первую в алфавитном порядке.
Вот что уже есть

```
txt = input("Введите текст: ")
mass = []
stxt = []
for i in txt:
    if i not in stxt:
        stxt.append(i)
for i in stxt:
    mass.append(txt.count(i))

mmax = mass.index(max(mass))
```

В конце я получаю индекс максимального числа. Но если там не одно такое число то он просто берет первое, а мне надо брать все из них. мах так не может есть ли другие способы

Comment: есть другие способы - https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-python/#use-the-collections-counter-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: Зачем все? В условиях просят только одну букву.

Comment: прочитайте свое условие внимательно. вам надо брать не все из них, а одну. максимальное количество у одной буквы, то берете ее. если у нескольких, то берете из них первую по алфавиту.

Comment: `print(min((-txt.count(c), c) for c in set(txt.replace(" ",""))[1])`

Comment: Ещё обратите внимание на наличие пробелов, которые не буква, но их количество у вас тоже считается.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = input('Введите текст: ') # ввод текса
letters = set(text) # делаем множество
letters.remove(' ') # пробел не буква - удаляем

letter_count = list()
for letter in letters:
    # (буква, кол-во вхождений)
    letter_count.append((letter, text.count(letter)))
# сортируем по убыванию частоты и возрастанию по порядку в алфавите
letter_count.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
print(letter_count[0])
```

Сократим код:

```
text = input('Введите текст: ')
letters = set(text).difference({' '})
letter_count = sorted([(letter, text.count(letter)) for letter in letters],
                      key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
print(letter_count[0])
```

И еще короче

```
text = input('Введите текст: ')
letter_count = sorted([(letter, text.count(letter)) for letter in set(text).difference({' '})],
                      key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
print(letter_count[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

У функции `max()` есть необязательный аргумент `key`. Для вашего примера ключом будет функция `count`. А чтобы *"Если такая буква не одна, то вывести первую в алфавитном порядке"* можно строку сначала отсортировать. Примерно так:

```
txt = input("Введите текст: ")
print(max(sorted(txt), key=txt.count))
'''

Введите текст: ddd ss aaa
'a'
```

Ну а если пробелы учитывать не надо, то от них можно избавиться с помощью `replace`